# Required Field validator for text box in asp Detailview while Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Detail view which its Edite command enabled , It returns my desired data ,and returned data from my database are required , meas they cannot be Empty , but in updating with detail view it gives me some textFields that user can put space it causes an exception from my database 
so how to put RequiredField for that textFields ?

thats my code

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="ناو :" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="ناوی بەکارهێنەر :" SortExpression="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile" HeaderText="مۆبــایل :" SortExpression="Mobile" />

        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="NormalButton"  ShowEditButton="True" CancelText="پاشگەزبوونەوە" EditText="دەستکاری کردن" UpdateText="گۆڕین" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="NormalButton" Text="گۆڕینی ژمارەی نهێنی" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066"   />


</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Plaese show your work. People can't read your mind..

Comment: Here is my code, I updated it , sorry I thought you mind reader , :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer . I Solved it ,thanks for your helps

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ناو :">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvTxtName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


            </EditItemTemplate>






        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ناوی بەکارهێنەر">

                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserame" Text='<%#Bind("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvtxtUserame" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserame" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <br />
                <asp:Label Visible="false" ID="lblDublicateUsername" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="ناوی بەکارهێنەر دووبارەیە"></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>


          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="مۆبایل">

                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Mobile") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMobile" Text='<%#Bind("Mobile") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvTxtMobile" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


            </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

While updating remove the spaces from "some textFields that user can put space" 
or you can make the textfields readonly.

Comment: no textFeilds are for entering a text for updating , they should be read an write

Comment: i cant see any textfields in you detailsview. post you textfields code.